# Timestamp is not same with database (laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, timezone

I have some data. On the database `mysql 8`. Created_at field seems like `2022-06-25 07:44:43.`

But when I fetch the data, it returns

`"created_at": "2022-06-25T05:44:43.000000Z"`

I have set my timezone from **config/app.php** as **Europe/France** but the time seems still 2 hours behind.

Which mechanism changes that time during the fetch? Why don't I get the same data from the database?

The code below solves my problem but I am just curious about this problem.

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) {
        return Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($value))
            ->timezone(env("APP_TIMEZONE"))
            ->toDateTimeString();
    }
```

Comment: Laravel allows you to [set the date format](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization#date-serialization) Eloquent uses. Do you have that set up by any chance?

Comment: Well, actually that Date Serialization does same job with which i have created getCreatedAtAttribute() on model. I have already a solution and thats another solution. Thank you for that. My question was about, why do i have to format the date? I mean, the database keeps the correct datetime anyway. But when i fetch the data, in the result it shows -2 hours behind. Im just wondering why does datetime change after the fetch? I just want to understand logic behind it. @rickdenhaan

Comment: The timestamp is formatted as an ISO string in the UTC timezone. That’s not how the raw MySQL query returns it, so something in Laravel or Eloquent is manipulating it first. That’s why I thought you might have date serialization configured, since that could cause this.

Answer (score 0):

The timezone on your database server is wrongly set.

If you are under linux run

```
$ sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Paris
```

Or the timezone you need